# Error in TextInput using react-native-paper and typescript

Tags: react-native, react-native-paper

I used TextInput in react-native-paper. But when I followed their documentation,but show errors.
[image]

Show the error like:

```
Type '{ label: string; value: string; onChangeText: (text: string) => void; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Pick<TextInputProps, "allowFontScaling" | "autoCapitalize" | "autoCorrect" | "autoFocus" | "blurOnSubmit" | "caretHidden" | "contextMenuHidden" | "defaultValue" | ... 116 more ... | "dense">': children, onPressIn, onPressOut, autoCompletets(2739)
```

versions:

```
"react": "16.13.1",
"react-native": "0.63.3",
"react-native-config": "^1.4.1",
"react-native-fast-image": "^8.3.4",
"react-native-paper": "^4.11.2",
"react-native-vector-icons": "^9.1.0"
```

used react native cli and not expo cli.

Comment: strange I'm trying the same code and works fine no type error, did you try to reinstall the package ?, even the type error should be on text inised onchangetext beacuse it should tell you the text already used before

Comment: Yep. Thank you. I also think same. It is typescript error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<TextInputPaper 
     autoComplete={false}
     label="Email"
     value={text}
     onChangeText={(text: string) =>
        setText(text)
     }
/>
```

I faced same type issue and when i add `autoComplete={false}` it gone